# Is $2^\omega$ homeomorphic to $3^\omega$ in the product topology?

Tags: general-topology

They don't seem to be, but I can't find a reason to say they aren't. And it wouldn't really surprise me if they actually are homeomorphic. Help?

Comment: Assuming that you’re giving $2$ and $3$ the discrete topology, they are indeed homeomorphic: both are homeomorphic to the middle-thirds Cantor set.

Comment: I know how to show that $2^\omega$ is homeomorphic to the middle thirds cantor set, how can I show the result for $3^\omega$?

Comment: One way – messy in detail but straightforward in principle – is to observe that although the most obvious way to think about the construction of the middle-thirds Cantor set is in terms of repeated splitting into pairs of closed intervals, one can think of it in terms of repeated splitting into triplets of closed intervals. The first split is into $[0,1/9],[2/9,1/3]$, and $[2/3,1]$. Each of these is similarly split into its first ninth, its third ninth, and its last third. In each split label the leftmost interval $0$, the middle one $1$, and the rightmost one $2$. Each point of the Cantor ...

Comment: ... set is the intersection of a unique decreasing nest of these intervals, and each decreasing nest determines a point of the Cantor set. Each nest also determines an infinite sequence in $3^\omega$, and it’s not *too* hard to check that the topologies agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Up to homeomorhphism, $2^\omega$ is the unique nonempty, perfect, compact metrizable and zero-dimensional space. Now consider the map $d \colon 3^\omega \times 3^\omega \to [0, 1]$, $(x,y) \mapsto 2^{-|x,y|}$ where $|x,y|$ is the least $n \in \omega$ such that $x(n) \neq y(n)$. I claim that this is a metric, its induced topology is the product topology and $(3^\omega, d)$ is a nonempty, perfect, compact metrizable and zero-dimensional space. (For $s \in 3^{< \omega}$ let $\mathcal N_s = \{ x \in 3^\omega \mid x \restriction \operatorname{length}(s) = s \}$. Then $\mathcal B = \{ \mathcal N_s \mid s \in 3^{< \omega} \}$ is a basis of clopen sets for the topology of $(3^\omega, d)$.)

Comment: Or without using metrics: $3^\omega$ has no isolated points (no non-trivial infinite product has), is compact using Tychonoff, metrisable because it has a countable base, zero-dimensional as a product of zero-dimensional spaces. So for every countable family of finite discrete spaces $F_n$, we know that $\prod_n F_n$ is the Cantor set.